# Doctrine. Cache. Entity relations

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, orm, doctrine

I have two Entities **Company** and **Storage** with One-To-Many Bidirectional relationship. Entities and their relations are cached (doctrine second level cache). The issue is that, when i create a new Storage entity, Company storages collection doesn't have this new entity until I clear the cache manually.

```
 AppBundle\Entity\Main\Company:
    type: entity
    table: main.company
    cache:
        usage: NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        legalName:
            type: string
            nullable: false
            length: 255
            options:
                fixed: false
            column: legal_name
   oneToMany:
      storages:
          targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Main\Storage
          mappedBy: company
          cascade: ["all"]
          orphanRemoval: true
          cache:
              usage: NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE


AppBundle\Entity\Main\Storage:
    type: entity
    table: main.storage
    cache:
        usage: NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            options:
                unsigned: false
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        storageName:
            type: string
            nullable: true
            length: 255
            options:
                fixed: false
            column: storage_name

    manyToOne:
        company:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Main\Company
            cascade: ["all"]
            fetch: LAZY
            mappedBy: null
            inversedBy: storages
            joinColumns:
                company_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: false
            cache:
                usage: NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE
```

This is action where **Storage** is created. There is nothing unusual.

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(StorageAddType::class, null);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if (!$form->isSubmitted()) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('Некорректный запрос');
    }
    if (!$form->isValid()) {
        throw new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\ValidatorException((string)$form->getErrors(true));
    }

    $doctrine = $this->getDoctrine();

    /**
     * @var Storage $storage
     */
    $storage = $form->getData();


    $manager = $doctrine->getManager();

    $manager->persist($storage);
    $manager->flush();
    return $this->createAjaxDataResponse($this->createSuccessMessage('Storage successfully added'));
}
```

Such behavior is watched only when i try to create new Entity (**Storage**). Then on update/delete actions - **Storages** collection of **Company** are updated.

Comment: Are you flushing the Object Manager ? Can you please paste some code of your save method ?

Comment: I added the code from the controller above

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly wrong with persisting data. You try to persist unserialized object from form into uknown repository via manager.

Try this:

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(StorageAddType::class, null);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
        $storage = new Storage();
        $storage->setVal1($form->get('Val1'));
        $storage->setVal2($form->get('Val2'));
        $em->persist($storage);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->createAjaxDataResponse($this->createSuccessMessage('Storage successfully added'));
    }

    return $this->render('YOUR_TWIG_LAYOUT', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

You can also try to persist whole object, if form is seriaized properly by serializing data into entity. Write method like `setValsFromForm($data)` and serialize vars from $data form.
Then change these lines:

`$storage->setVal1($form->get('Val1'));
$storage->setVal2($form->get('Val2'));`

into

`$storage->setValsFromForm($form->getData());`

Also:
Exceptions and form validations should be handled by Form Validator in form class, not in controller. Exception is when you create form via formbuilderinterface in the controller, but you add logic there, not outside $form class.

Comment: Symfony 3.4.  Doctrine 2.6

Comment: I see clearly why You are doing it wrong; You are persisting non-serialized object into unknown repository. Doctrine just cant handle Your controller; Try this: